# How to prevent the enter key from making a new line in a multiple line text box?

Tags: c#, textbox

I want to prevent the Enter key from making a new line inside the multiple line text box using the KeyDown event. Despite clearing the textBox using textBox.Text = "" or textBox.Clear(), it behaves like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvdnp.png

```
private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
            textBox2.Text = "";
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to prevent the Enter key? What if a user pastes some text containing newlines?

Comment: I agree with CodeCaster, if you only want to take one line then use a single line `textbox`, otherwise add another button for the person to press to submit the `textbox`.

Comment: I join previous commentators, but if you really need to do it that way, then you use `KeyUp` handler and after erasing text add `e.Handled = true;`.

Comment: To handle the pasted text, use the `TextBox.TextChanged` event and erase the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting a bit and it seems like the new line from the Enter key is added at the `KeyUp` event. So this should work (note that I use `KeyUp` instead of `KeyDown`):

```
private void textBox2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
        textBox2.Text = "";
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Or you could set the cursor position with

```
textBox2.Select(0, 0);
```

instead of using the line `e.Handled = true;`

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you want to define a text box as multi-line and only accept one long line from it?

Seems as though you only want a single line text box.  Define your text box as single line and set it up at design time to *look* like a multi-line text box.

Another option would be to leave the box as-is and allow the user to enter it with the newline characters in it.  Then, when you need the data, simply remove all newline characters *after the fact*.